# Randomly choose between numbers that yields a specific amount of binary 1's

Tags: random-generation

I want to randomly choose between any decimal numbers that - when converted to binary numbers - will produce the same amount of binary 1's within a total of 16 bits. It doesn't matter which bits that are 1's as long as i can randomly choose from all of the variations.

For example, if i wanted the result to be one 1, and 15 0's within the 16 bits, i would have to randomly pick any of the numbers: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 et c.

Therefore, i'd need some help figuring out a function that allows me to:

1. first input a specified sum of 1's: n
2. then determine which decimal values that produces any variation of n 1's within the 16 bits.
3. and lastly, randomly choose from any of these numbers.

Any input would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The algorithm to use depends on (a) the capabilities of your software platform; (b) how many such random draws you need; (c) how large the number of digits $n$ is; and (d) how large the number of possible results $\binom{n}{k}$ (where $k$ is the number of ones) is.

Most statistical work is done with 32 or 64 signed integer and/or double-precision IEEE floating point numbers, so I will assume that of (a).  Here is a set of solutions illustrated with working `R` code.  To be specific, they all draw uniformly, independently, and randomly from the set $\mathcal{B}(n,k)$ of integers which, when represented in binary, have up to $n$ digits of which exactly $k$ are ones.

1. **You need a single random integer.**  Take a sample $i_1, i_2, \ldots, i_k$ without replacement from the set of places $0,1,\ldots, n-1$ and return $2^{i_1} + 2^{i_2} + \cdots + 2^{i_k}.$

   ```
   rchoose <- function(n, k) sum(2^sample(0:(n-1), k))
   ```

   This algorithm has $O(n)$ time and storage requirements.
2. **You need a large number $N$ of random integers where $n$ and $k$ are small.**  "Small" means both (1) your system accurately represents all integers through $2^{n}-1$ and (2) you have enough speed and RAM to compute and store all the elements of $\mathcal{B}(n,k).$

   The solution is to generate an array representing all elements of $\mathcal{B}(n,k)$ and then (rapidly) draw randomly from this array:

   ```
   rchoose.many <- function(N, n, k) {
     b <- colSums(2^combn(0:(n-1), k))
     sample(b, N, replace=TRUE)
   }
   ```

   This algorithm requires $O(n \binom{n}{k})$ time to initialize plus $O(N)$ additional time to run.  Its storage requirements are $O(n \binom{n}{k})$ (but could be reduced to $O(\binom{n}{k})$ by accumulating the values in a loop during initialization).
3. **You need a large number of random integers where $n$ and $k$ are not small.**  You're still limited by the need to represent $n$-digit binary integers in your system.  About the best you can do is to loop $N$ times over the single-draw solution (1):

   ```
   rchoose.many.large <- function(N, n, k) {
     replicate(N, rchoose(n, k))
   }
   ```

   This takes $O(Nn)$ time and $O(n)$ storage.

Comparing the asymptotic requirements provides a criterion for selecting the appropriate solution in any situation.

#### Examples

These timings (on one modest workstation) provide some indication of the possibilities.

```
system.time(x <- rchoose.many(1, 33, 7))   # 8 sec.
system.time(x <- rchoose.many(1e5, 33, 7)) # 8 sec.
system.time(x <- rchoose.many(1, 33, 16))  # (Not run: would take about 35 min.)

system.time(x <- rchoose.many.large(1e5, 33, 7))  # 0.8 sec.
system.time(x <- rchoose.many.large(1e5, 33, 16)) # 0.9 sec.
```

Here's a histogram of one largish sample (of a million draws) showing the distribution for $n=10,k=4.$  The bins have to be wider than $1$, for otherwise the counts will be either $0$ or close to a constant (because the distribution is uniform on $\mathcal{B}(10,4)$).  I chose a width of $4:$

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=rchoose.many(1e6, 10, 4)), aes(x)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=4)
```

[image: Figure]